# How to make delayed payment to one receiver using Paypal or Stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, stripe-payments

I have an application, that process payment to application owner.
When user clicks "buy" on an item, the checkout operation should authorize certain  amount on the user's account until some date. And when that date comes authorized money will be captured from user's account to application owner's account.
There is also a possibility, that user may cancel this authorization through the application.

We are free to user Paypal API or Stripe. Which is better and **how it could be implemented?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is possible through paypal adaptive payment api.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what does 'freeze certain amount on the user account' mean, but you can surely transfer the amount to a holding account(admin account) and then on the particular date you can transfer it to the owner's account, meanwhile if the user cancels the payment the amount can be transferred from holding account back to user's account. This option is there in paypal.

Comment: we need to authorize the amount once user clicks on a buy button. and then in a few days we need to capture his amount to the owner account

Comment: Can you give a name of option from merchant account, which gives this possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a functionality called auth/capture. What you're essentially doing is authorizing the funds (holding them on the user's payment source) and then capturing them at a later time. This is the same premise as a hotel putting a hold on your credit card for incidentals, and later canceling the hold.

You can do all of this with the PayPal REST API. Here are the features you're looking for:

- Authorizing funds: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#authorizations
- Capturing funds (at a later time): https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#captures
- Voiding (canceling) an authorized hold of funds: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#void-an-authorization

Here's the Ruby SDK that you'll probably want to take a look at using, to make the authorization process easier: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Ruby-SDK

A few notes here. With authorization, I believe the funds are guaranteed to be there for 3 days. You can continue trying to capture the funds for up to, I believe, 29 days, but the funds are not guaranteed to be there.

Hope that helps